# POWERSHELL remove folder older than x days

Tags: powershell, date

I have my code below, but I don't understant it does not remove the directory that I want,
I want to remove folder than x days, the folder it is in array, but he delete it at each time;

I want to backup folder older x days with a rename, and delete backup folder older than 2xdays

```
$Folders = "totobck", "tatabck", "toto", "tata"
$Daysback = "-1"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.Days($Daysback)


foreach ($Fold in $Folders){
If (Test-Path $Fold){ 

If (($Fold | | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete.AddDays($Daysback) }) 
-and ($Fold -like '*bck')) {

  Remove-Item $Fold
  Write-Host $Fold " old backup folder, do delete it"
}

ElseIf((($Fold | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete }) -and !($Fold -like '*bck'))){  
    Rename-Item $Fold $Fold"bck"
    Write-Host $Fold " date more than x days, so Renamed it"      
      } else { 
    Write-Host  $Fold " Do nothing" 
    continue }

} else {
Write-Host  $Fold " Does not exit, do nothing"
}
}
```

Comment: try it with this `$DatetoDelete = (Get-Date).AddDays($Daysback)` and note it has to be a negative number, e.g -31

Comment: it change nothing

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Did you try to debug your code in Powershell ISE?

Comment: thank you very much, I execute my code with Powershell ISE, but I don't know to use debug mode

Comment: You've got a number of syntax errors in there. You should start by loading this up in the [PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6) or in VSCode with the [PowerShell Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) . That way you can use IntelliSense to see where the errors are and single-step through your code to see what the values of your different variables and expressions are.

Comment: in my computer, I don't have syntax error, I can execute the code without problem, but it delete folder each time, I think I have probleme, there $Fold | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete.AddMinutes($Daysback) }

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you want to do can happen without the `If` tests by using `Where-Object`.

Here's an example of a sequence of commands that deletes all files older than 3 days:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays( -3 ) } | 
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_ -WhatIf -Verbose }
```

Here's an example that renames all files older than one day:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays( -1 ) } | 
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "$($_.FullName).bak" -WhatIf -Verbose }
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` when you're ready for the actual deletion and renames to happen after experimenting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but where I have to put my local variable $Fold ? for each directory